# Inserting pictures as shape into cell, based on cell value and rename them to cell value weird working

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro where I am inserting pictures as shapes into merged cells (based on cell color) and then I name them with cell value (its a formula). The cell value is the picture path.

```
Sub INSERTPICTURES()
Dim shp As Shape
With Sheets("Condition_report")
    Dim cella As Range

    'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("L2") & "\2_handover\CONDITION_SURVEY_REPORT\SURVEY_REPORT_" & Range("L2") & ".xlsm")

    For Each cella In .Range("A51:F200").Cells

        If cella.Interior.ColorIndex = 15 Then

        Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=cella, LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=cella.MergeArea.Left, Top:=cella.MergeArea.Top, Width:=cella.MergeArea.Width, Height:=cella.MergeArea.Height)
        shp.Name = cella.Value

        'ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add cella, cella.Value
        On Error Resume Next

        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

The picture insert method working fine. However if I inactivate the `On Error Resume Next` line it generates error, says: cannot find the pictures (probably because the macro does not care if a cell is merged).

So If I keep the `On Error Resume Next` line active it load all the pictures and name them with their cell value.. however not all of the are correct

e.g.:
The cell value is:

```
E:\gdrive\work\catsurveys\catsurveys2018\P7C\P7C17630_1\2_HANDOVER\SITE_PHOTOGRAPHS\PHOTOGRAPHS_OF_DAMAGE\MASTER BEDROOM\2\PIC2.JPG
```

The macro insert the correct picture, however it name it like this: 
   E:\gdrive\work\catsurveys\catsurveys2018\P7C\P7C17630_1\2_HANDOVER\SITE_PHOTOGRAPHS\PHOTOGRAPHS_OF_DAMAGE\MASTER BEDROOM\6\PIC4.JPG

I guess this is because of the merged cells, but I cannot figure out the problem.

If I replace the range to cells,

```
For Each cella In .Range("A53,a73,a102,a122").Cells
```

everything works as expected.

Comment: First of all remove `On Error Resume Next` this makes you just blind for any errors, it hides them but they still occur. So you just don't see what happens. Remove it and see if you get any errors.  `On Error Resume Next` should never be used without a proper error handling.

Comment: Ok, I did. It fails now at the first bit of macro on picture insert after the first picture. It say cannot find the file. So what I did I focused on the first 2 picture 'For Each cella In .Range("A51:f73").Cells'. But it fails, however the picture location is correct and if I activate the 'On Error Resume Next', the macro will load both pictures...

Comment: ok, it fails because of the merged cells....

Comment: Ok, so if your question is still not solved please [edit] your original question to the actual code and your actual question to that code. A screenshot of your sheet might help too.

Comment: I think you are looping somehow wrong. Can you provide a screenshot of the sheet where we can see which cells contain data for the pictures? If we don't know how your sheet looks like and where are merged cells it would be hard to help.

Comment: I think its working fine now by adding cella.UnMerge to the loop.